# How to Represent Objects with Multiple Fields in the MongoDB Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, aggregation-framework

I'm creating an aggregation pipeline in Java using MongoDB and, of course, the MongoDB Java driver.

I've figured out how to do what I want in the Mongo Shell, but I'm not sure how to translate this into Java, particularly the whole concept of an object with commas in it, as shown below.

```
{$project: {sleep: {"date": 1, "hours": 1}}}
```

Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out one great way to do this is the following:

```
BasicDBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("sleep", new BasicDBObject().append("date", 1).append("hours", 1)));
```

Then you can call your aggregation command as follows:

```
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(commandOne, commandTwo, Project, CommandThree);
```

Hope this helps :)